# $q.when promise rejection when boolean value passed

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, q

I have the below segment in my code, I know $q.when will resolve the promise with the given value and never going to be rejected. In my case, I pass the boolean value either true or false to this segment and I can see error call back function is executed after success call back function. 
In a Nutshell, once the value(true/false) is passed to 'when', first then in $q.when is executed once after this execution next then section is executed.

My question is why its calling error call back function after successful resolve?

```
   $q.when(true/false) 
        .then(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                return doSave();
            }
        })
        .then(function() {
            goNextPage();
        });
```

Comment: where is your error callback? how these two `then` statements deal with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .catch() for the error callback. .then() is the success callback. You have added two success callbacks.